# Como faço um validador de cpf para meus valores do banco de dados?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Eu tenho o código abaixo, que aceita valores em suas inputs e depois os envia para o banco de dados.
Eu quero que, quando o usuário clique em enviar, caso o cpf seja inválido(EX:111.111.111-11), ele não envie nenhum valor ao banco e mostre um alert na tela indicando que nada foi adicionado, **preciso de um if que tenha como condição o cpf válido, só se o cpf for válido os valores serão enviados**

**Aqui temos as inputs**

```html
 <form action="Dados.php"  method="POST" >
   <table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Cpf</th>
    <th>Cep</th>
    <th>Rua</th>
    <th>Bairro</th>
    <th>Cidade</th>
    <th>Estado</th>
    <th>Ibge</th>
    </tr>   
   </thead>
   
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="nom" required><br></td>
    
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cpf"  name="cpf" required><br></td>
    
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cep" name="end" required><br></td>
    
          <td><input name="rua" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="rua" required /><br /></td>
          
          <td><input name="bairro" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="bairro" required/><br /></td>
          
          <td><input name="cidade" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="cidade" required/><br /></td>
          
          <td><input name="uf" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="uf" required/><br /></td>
         
          <td><input name="ibge" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="ibge" required/><br /></td>
    
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
   <input type="submit" value="Criar Registro" onclick="function validaCPF()" class="btn btn-default"><input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Voltar"
onclick="window.location='/Banco_de_dados/index.php';"/>
   </form>
```

**E aqui temos o código que envia os valores ao Banco**

```
<body>
<?php
//declarando variaveis//
    $servername = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $dbname = 'meubd';
    $nome = $_POST['nom'];
    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
    $cep = $_POST['end'];
    $rua = $_POST['rua'];
    $bairro = $_POST['bairro'];
    $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
    $uf = $_POST['uf'];
    $ibge = $_POST['ibge'];
    function validaCPF($cpf = null) {

        // Verifica se um número foi informado
        if(empty($cpf)) {
            return false;
            echo "Cpf";
        }

        // Elimina possivel mascara
        $cpf = ereg_replace('[^0-9]', '', $cpf);
        $cpf = str_pad($cpf, 11, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

        // Verifica se o numero de digitos informados é igual a 11
        if (strlen($cpf) != 11) {
            return false;
        }
        // Verifica se nenhuma das sequências invalidas abaixo
        // foi digitada. Caso afirmativo, retorna falso
        else if ($cpf == '00000000000' ||
                $cpf == '11111111111' ||
                $cpf == '22222222222' ||
                $cpf == '33333333333' ||
                $cpf == '44444444444' ||
                $cpf == '55555555555' ||
                $cpf == '66666666666' ||
                $cpf == '77777777777' ||
                $cpf == '88888888888' ||
                $cpf == '99999999999') {
                    return false;
                    // Calcula os digitos verificadores para verificar se o
                    // CPF é válido
                } else {

                    for ($t = 9; $t < 11; $t++) {

                        for ($d = 0, $c = 0; $c < $t; $c++) {
                            $d += $cpf{$c} * (($t + 1) - $c);
                        }
                        $d = ((10 * $d) % 11) % 10;
                        if ($cpf{$c} != $d) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    return true;
                    $sql = 'INSERT INTO pessoas VALUES ("'.$nome.'", "'.$cpf.'", "'.$cep.'" , "'.$rua.'", "'.$bairro.'", "'.$cidade.'", "'.$uf.'", "'.$ibge.'")';
                    //verificando se os valores foram inseridos//
                    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                        echo "<br>Os valores foram adicionados corretamente";
                    } else {
                        echo "<br>Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;

                    }

                }
    }

//conectando ao banco de dados//verificando conexão//
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Conecxão Falhou: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    echo "Conexao foi um sucesso";


//fechando conexão//
    $conn ->close();
?>
</body>
```

Como já falei antes, podem ter muitos erros no meu código, por isso peço a ajuda de vocês.

Comment: Existe uma API pronta para este tipo de validações, é só importar do Maven, segue o [link][1]
[1]: https://github.com/jereztech/validation-br-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A única forma de garantir que um CPF é válido é verificando seus dígitos verificadores. Um CPF é formado da seguinte forma: XXX.XXX.XXX-DD. Os "X" são os números bases e os "DD" são os dígitos verificadores dos "X".

O calculo desses dois dígitos verificadores é feito através do **Módulo 11**

Para entender como ele funciona:

Mais informações a respeito do Módulo 11 você pode encontrar [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%ADgito_verificador)

A baixo um código em Java (não muito explicativo) mas que recebe uma String (de números) e retorna o Módulo 11 desse valor.

```
public Integer getDVModulo11(String valor){
    StringBuilder valorFiltrado = new StringBuilder().append(valor);
    Integer indiceMultiplicacao = 2;
    Integer soma = 0;
    //1º PASSO
    for (Integer i = valorFiltrado.length()-1; i > -1; i--) {
        Integer numero = Character.getNumericValue(valorFiltrado.toString().charAt(i));
        Integer multiplicacao = (numero * indiceMultiplicacao);
        //2º PASSO
        soma = soma + multiplicacao;
        if(indiceMultiplicacao < 9) {
            indiceMultiplicacao++;
        }else{
            indiceMultiplicacao = 2;
        }
    }
    //3º PASSO
    Integer resultado = soma % 11;
    //4º PASSO
    resultado = 11 - resultado;
    if(resultado > 9){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo código, mas o problema que realmente estou tendo é que quando digito o meu cpf e ele passa pela função por mais que de false ele envia o valor ao banco de dados, consegue me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Não sei se no PHP também existem esses problemas, mas no java ao se comparar String não se usa "==" e sim .equals(), talvez seja esse o problema. Ex.: $cpf == '88888888888'.

Comment: Pois então, esse é o mesmo código usado pela receita federal, era suposto ele funcionar, mas não é esse o problema, oque eu não consigo fazer é botar o código para fazer um verificação onde se o cpf for válido adiciona dados na tabela e se não for nada acontece. Oque eu faço?

Comment: A função validaCPF tem mais coisas que validar um cpf no seu código. Faça uma função que tem como objetivo realmente só verificar se o cpf é valido e depois crie uma função que só adiciona no banco com um if na função validaCPF, caso a validaCPF retornar true ele adiciona, se não ele não adiciona.

Comment: consegui fazer com que ele enviasse os dados, eu fiz como você disse no comentário e funcionou perfeitamente por isso vou marcar a  sua resposta como certa

Answer (score 0):

Tu poderia verificar o CPF informado pelo cliente com uma função JS.

Ficaria assim:

```
    <script>
 function validaCPF(cpf)
  {
    var numeros, digitos, soma, i, resultado, digitos_iguais;
    digitos_iguais = 1;
    if (cpf.length < 11)
          return false;
    for (i = 0; i < cpf.length - 1; i++)
          if (cpf.charAt(i) != cpf.charAt(i + 1))
                {
                digitos_iguais = 0;
                break;
                }
    if (!digitos_iguais)
          {
          numeros = cpf.substring(0,9);
          digitos = cpf.substring(9);
          soma = 0;
          for (i = 10; i > 1; i--)
                soma += numeros.charAt(10 - i) * i;
          resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
          if (resultado != digitos.charAt(0))
                return false;
          numeros = cpf.substring(0,10);
          soma = 0;
          for (i = 11; i > 1; i--)
                soma += numeros.charAt(11 - i) * i;
          resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
          if (resultado != digitos.charAt(1))
                return false;
          return true;
          }
    else
        return false;
  }
    </script>
```

Segue teste: https://jsfiddle.net/jzvtcLxq/