# Como verificar se há apenas números no CPF e CEP em SQL

Tags: sql

Estou fazendo um trabalho de banco de dados e preciso verificar se o CPF e CEP possuem apenas números, já que estão como `varchar`, não precisa ser válido (por enquanto), mas caso haja letras, não ser registrado. Abaixo segue o código

```
CREATE TABLE clientes (
cod_cliente SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
nome VARCHAR (60) NOT NULL,
CPF VARCHAR (11) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
telefone INTEGER,
data_cadastro DATE NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE endereco(
cod_end SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
logradouro VARCHAR (50),
cep VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
cod_cidade INTEGER NOT NULL,
cod_cliente INTEGER NOT NULL 
);


CREATE TABLE estado(
cod_estado SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
nome VARCHAR (60) NOT NULL,
uf VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE cidade(
cod_cidade SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
nome VARCHAR (60) NOT NULL,
cod_estado INTEGER NOT NULL
);





ALTER TABLE endereço ADD CONSTRAINT endereço_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (cod_cliente) REFERENCES clientes (cod_cliente);
ALTER TABLE endereço ADD CONSTRAINT estado_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (cod_cidade) REFERENCES cidade (cod_cidade);
ALTER TABLE cidade ADD CONSTRAINT cidade_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (cod_estado) REFERENCES estado (cod_estado);




ALTER TABLE clientes ADD CONSTRAINT tabela_ck CHECK (coluna1 > 0);


ALTER TABLE tabela ADD CONSTRAINT tabela_ck CHECK (coluna1 > 0);


ALTER TABLE tabela ADD CONSTRAINT tabela_ck CHECK (coluna1 > 0);


ALTER TABLE tabela ADD CONSTRAINT tabela_ck CHECK (coluna1 > 0);







INSERT INTO estado VALUES ('Rio Grande do Sul', 'RS');
INSERT INTO estado VALUES ('Santa Catarina', 'SC');
INSERT INTO estado VALUES ('Parana', 'PR');
INSERT INTO estado VALUES ('Mato Grosso', 'MT');
INSERT INTO estado VALUES ('Minas Gerais','MG');



INSERT INTO cidade VALUES ('Caxias do Sul',);
INSERT INTO cidade VALUES ('Florianópolis',);
INSERT INTO cidade VALUES ('Cabo Verde',);
INSERT INTO cidade VALUES ('Cascavel',);
INSERT INTO cidade VALUES ('Cuibá',);


INSERT INTO clientes VALUES ('Naiara', '03365282050', 'naiara@enttry.com.br', '54991207030','2019/11/28');
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES ('Mateus', '03033611079', 'mateus@gov.com.br', '5491888899','2019/11/28');
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES ('Lucas', '75424991068', 'lucas@gmail.com, '5499224455');
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES ('Gabriel', '03006364074', 'gabrieldazareia@gmail.com', '5499433379','2019/11/28');
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES ('Janaina', '03268542783', 'janaiana@gmail.com', '48981542365','2019/11/28');
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES ('Marcos', '02565985210', 'marcos@gmail.com', '54991234567','2019/11/28');
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES ('Joanna', '89652336587', 'joanna@gmail.com', '54999876543','2019/11/28');
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES ('Juliana', '05263587412', 'juliana@gmail.com', '54996548752','2019/11/28');
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES ('Alexandre', '96385274114', 'alexandre@gmail.com', '54984526314','2019/11/28');
INSERT INTO clientes VALUES ('Gustavo', '12345678998', 'gustavo@gmail.com', '54991105287','2019/11/28');


INSERT INTO endereco (logradouro, cep, cod_cidade, cod_cliente)
VALUES ('Rua Amabile Fontana', '95010000', , ), ('Avenida Castelo Branco', '95250000', , ), ('Rua Bela Vista', '69999000', , ), ('Travessa Antônio Carneiro Pinto', '90010020', , ), ('Rua 15 de Novembro'  '98995000', , );
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como faço um validador de cpf para meus valores do banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127681/como-fa%c3%a7o-um-validador-de-cpf-para-meus-valores-do-banco-de-dados)

Comment: Ele não precisa ser válido (por enquanto) preciso ver se ele tem só números, e não registrar caso tenha letras

Comment: Seria legal você [edit] sua pergunta e adicionar a tag do SGBD que você está usando. Ex.: [tag:mysql], [tag:sqlserver], [tag:postgresql], [tag:sqlite], etc...

Comment: você pode trocar para int, isso irá bloquear insert de caractere não num

Answer (score 0):

Isso pode ser feito dentro do próprio `input`, se criar um:

```
<input type="number" name="cpf" />
```

Ele irá enviar apenas números. O que tu terá que ter cuidado é que este campo pode enviar números negativos, porém, tu pode fazer uma validação no PHP com o `str_replace()`:

```
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];

$replace = str_replace('-', '', $cpf);
```

Comment: O AP quer validar isso no SQL, e usar `number` em um input de CPF só criará mais problemas, pois CPFs que começarem com zero vão ter número menor de dígitos. Aí é mais fácil simplesmente usar string e fazer `preg_replace("/\D+/", "", $cpf);` que já remove tudo que não for dígito...

Answer (score 0):

Caso esteja utilizando o PostgreSQL, que me parece ser o caso, você pode utilizar expressões regulares:

```
teste=# SELECT regexp_replace('03365282050', '[[:digit:]]+', '', 'g') = '';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 registro)

teste=# SELECT regexp_replace('03365abc050', '[[:digit:]]+', '', 'g') = '';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 registro)
```

ou, de maneira mais simples:

```
teste=# SELECT '03365123050' ~ '[^[:digit:]]';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 registro)

teste=# SELECT '03365abc050' ~ '[^[:digit:]]';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 registro)
```